# Facebook Event - Wall Post not showing photo when logged off

Tags: facebook, facebook-photos, facebook-events

I am having a problem with a Facebook fan-page.  I created an event and then made a wall post with a photo.  The wall post with photo is visible when I am logged in.  But when I log out, the photo is not visible.  See below:

http://www.facebook.com/events/184855698318800/

Otherwise here is what it looks like when I logged in:

[image]

I would like the wall post with photo to be able to show when logged off.  Is this possible?